# How to get a Open Source License which prevents people from modifying/forking/commercial use/duplicating?

Tags: solidity

How to get an Open Source License which prevents people from modifying/forking/commercial use/duplicating the smart contracts like Uniswap?

Answer (score 1):

If users cannot modify and fork the source code under the same license, it is not [open source by Open Source Initiative definition](https://opensource.org/osd).

Answer (score 0):

@Mikko said, an "Open Source" License by definition allows for forking.

What you're looking for is a closed source license, you might want to go to https://choosealicense.com/ and figure out what works best for you, otherwise you might not want to make your project open source.

Comment: Then, How get a closed source license?

Comment: By definition, the [No license](https://choosealicense.com/no-permission/) means all rights reserved. Or, you can do something like this: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/68150